# Enterprise Custom field formula in MS Project server 2016

Tags: ms-project

I am trying to implement a custom formula in Enterprise Custom field of MS Project.
Formula is as below:

````
   ``` ([Baseline Cost]*[DurationCustom])/[Baseline Duration]
       `[Baseline Cost] and [Baseline Duration] are fields directly from MS Project,
       [DurationCustom] is an enterprise custom field with Entity:task and Type:Number.` ```
````

For instance if

```
[Baseline Cost] = 1      ----- Type:Cost(₹1.00)
[DurationCustom] = 100   ----- Type:Number(100)
[Baseline Duration] = 100 ----Type:Number(100d)
Expected result: 1
Current result: 0.21
```

Can anyone suggest if the error is due to the data type.
Also, if there is a possibility to convert "100d" to simply a number "100".

P.S: I am using MS Project server 2016.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following. Break down your formula into three parts (separately) to see what value appears for each of the variables. For example, what do you get with the following:
Number1 = [Baseline Cost]
Then do the same for [DurationCustom] and [Baseline Duration]. That will tell you how Project "sees" the values and likely tell you why you get the result you do.

As far as converting "100d" to "100", yes it can be done but it isn't necessary. The "100d" is a display value based on your option setting. Internally, "100d" is stored as a number, in minutes, without any unit suffix.

John